# IEEE floating point signalling NaN (sNaN) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, ieee-754

Is there any way to define signaling NaN in Haskell? I found two approaches to deal with NaNs:

1) use 0/0, which produces quite nan

2) package [Data.Number.Transfinite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logfloat-0.12.1/docs/Data-Number-Transfinite.html), which has no signaling NaNs too.

PS Is there any way to put Word64 bit by bit into Double without writing C library?

Comment: [`Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Prelude.html) supports checking if a number is `NaN` using `isNaN`, and even `RealFloat` has the function `isIEEE` as well.  You can use the [`ieee754`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.7.3/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html) for more specific functions.

Comment: @bheklilr, ieee754 module has no signaling NaNs either. Checking for NaNs is quite trivial : x == x is False.

Comment: If you want to convert `Word64` to `Double` bit by bit, you can use `unsafeCoerce`. You may get undefined behavior for other types whose size in bytes is not the same, or whose level of boxing differs.

Comment: You can use `unsafeCoerce` to cast bit-by-bit between `Word64` and `Double` in GHC in a very unportable way, but sNaN is still not supported because it's not implemented in the `Num` instance. The `NaN` just acts like the `0.0/0` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found one non-portable way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Data.Word (Word64, Word32)
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
foreign import ccall "fenv.h feenableexcept" -- GNU extension
    enableexcept :: CInt -> IO ()

class HasNAN a where
    signalingNaN :: a
    quietNaN :: a

instance HasNAN Double where
    signalingNaN = unsafeCoerce (0x7ff4000000000000::Word64)
    quietNaN = unsafeCoerce (0x7ff8000000000000::Word64)

instance HasNAN Float where
    signalingNaN = unsafeCoerce (0x7fa00000::Word32)
    quietNaN = unsafeCoerce (0x7fc00000::Word32)

main = do
    enableexcept 1 -- FE_INVALID in my system
    print $ show $ 1 + (quietNaN :: Float) -- works
    print $ show $ 1 + (signalingNaN :: Float) -- fails
```

which perfectly fails. It turned out that FPU exceptions are a bad idea for Haskell. They are disabled by default for a good reason. They are OK if you debug C/C++/something else in gdb. I don't want to debug Haskell core dumps due to its non-imperative nature. Enabling `FE_INVALID` exceptions causes 0/0 and add to NaNs in `Data.Number.Transfinite` and `GHC.Real` to crash. But 0/0 calculated before enableexcept doesn't produce exceptions in addition.

I will use some simple errors check in my task. I need `sNaN` in just one place.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `Data.Maybe`?

You would use `Maybe Float` as datatype (assuming you want to use `Float`), and `Just x` for the non-NaN value `x`, whereas `Nothing` would represent NaN.

However, you'd need to radd at least a `Num` instance to be able to calculate using `Maybe Float` instead of Float. You can use `fromJust` as an utility function for this.

Whether this is expressed as *qNaN* or *sNaN* entirely depends on your implementation.

Comment: Maybe is a substitute for quite NaN, not signaling. 1 + sNaN = exception, 1 + qNaN = qNaN. I would prefer some hack to define sNaN. It looks simpler than defining Num instance.

Comment: @user3161163 What would be the problem of simply defining a `Num` instance that throws `error`s? It isn't that hard at all. What type of NaN is done with Maybe entirely depends on the operator definition...

Comment: I mean that if I deal with Maybe as Monad I get something like qNaN

Comment: @user3161163 Maybe I'm not understanding your problem correctly, but why would you get qNaN? Maybe itself does not define any numeric operations. `instance Num (Maybe Float)` would be what you declare. For example `(+) Nothing _ = error "signal nan"`, `(+) _ Nothing = error "signal nan"`, `(+) (Just a) (Just b) = (fromJust a) + (fromJust b)`?

Comment: I mean it is some surprise that Maybe works different ways as Monad and Num instances. Maybe semantics is closer to qNaN than sNaN. Of course I can do such Num instance. Probably with my own Maybe. Anyway this is not a solution for my problem, I don't want to replace all Float to Maybe Float in my code. 
PS your answer is very Haskell way and is good for some other situations.

Comment: @user3161163 Thanks ;-) If you can't/don't want to replace your Floats with something else, I doubt that there will be any solution to that problem (sidenote: use `type MyFloat = Maybe Float`, then `sed -i -e 's/Float/MyFloat/g/' *.hs` or similar), because even if someone found a library, I doubt it wouldnt use its own float type.

Comment: @user3161163 I just had another idea if replacing is not an option for you. Ill try to put together an answer.

Comment: @user3161163 Please have a look at my new answer which replaces custom float types by custom operators

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom operators instead of custom types like this (this avoids replacing any `Float` in your code`)

```
snanPlus :: Float -> Float -> Float
snanPlus a b = if isNaN(a) then error "snan"
                           else if isNaN(b)
                                then error "snan"
                                else a + b

-- Some testing code
main = do
    print $ 3.0 `snanPlus` 5.0 -- 8.0
    print $ (0/0) `snanPlus` 5.0 -- error
```

The second `print` triggers the error.

Note: I'm not sure if there is a better way of formatting this, and you should probably not use concrete types in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data.Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Ratio.html) to produce Nan/Infinity by using the ratios 1/0 (infinity) or 0/0 (NaN).

A faster but less portable approach is to use `GHC.Real` which exports `infinity` and `notANumber`.

```
infinity, notANumber :: Rational
infinity   = 1 :% 0
notANumber = 0 :% 0
```

Usage:

```
Prelude Data.Ratio GHC.Real> fromRational notANumber :: Float
NaN
```

For checking `NaN`/`infinity`, Prelude has two functions `isNaN` and `isInfinite`.

Comment: OP knows that, I suppose.

Comment: I found it hard to interpret the question, so I may have answered it incorrectly.

Comment: OP is asking about whether Haskell/GHC supports a signalling `NaN` (one that raises some kind of error if used in an arithmetic expression).

Comment: AFAIK what youre describing @kvanberendonck is qNaN

Comment: Maybe a wrapper type could help here.

Comment: @kvanberendonck That's what I thought of, see the comments of the `Maybe` answer above. However the OP didnt want to replace all floats. Considering this, I think a wrapping operator will do better (see my other answer above)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
newtype SNaN a = SNaN { unSNaN :: a}


liftSNaN :: RealFloat a => (a -> a) -> (SNaN a -> SNaN a)
liftSNaN f (SNaN x)
  | isNaN x = error "NaN"
  | otherwise = SNaN . f $ x

liftSNaN' :: RealFloat a => (a -> b) -> (SNaN a -> b)
liftSNaN' f (SNaN x)
  | isNaN x = error "NaN"
  | otherwise = f $ x

liftSNaN2 :: RealFloat a => (a -> a -> a) -> (SNaN a -> SNaN a -> SNaN a)
liftSNaN2 f (SNaN x) (SNaN y)
  | isNaN x || isNaN y = error "NaN"
  | otherwise = SNaN $ f x y

liftSNaN2' :: RealFloat a => (a -> a -> b) -> (SNaN a -> SNaN a -> b)
liftSNaN2' f (SNaN x) (SNaN y)
  | isNaN x || isNaN y = error "NaN"
  | otherwise = f x y


instance RealFloat a => Eq (SNaN a)
  where (==) = liftSNaN2' (==)
        (/=) = liftSNaN2' (/=)


instance RealFloat a => Ord (SNaN a)
  where compare = liftSNaN2' compare
        (<) = liftSNaN2' (<)
        (>=) = liftSNaN2' (>=)
        (>) = liftSNaN2' (>)
        (<=) = liftSNaN2' (<=)
        max = liftSNaN2 max
        min = liftSNaN2 min


instance (Show a, RealFloat a) => Show (SNaN a)
  where show = liftSNaN' show


instance RealFloat a => Num (SNaN a)
  where (+) = liftSNaN2 (+)
        (*) = liftSNaN2 (*)
        (-) = liftSNaN2 (-)
        negate = liftSNaN negate
        abs = liftSNaN abs
        signum = liftSNaN signum
        fromInteger = SNaN . fromInteger


instance RealFloat a => Fractional (SNaN a)
  where (/) = liftSNaN2 (/)
        recip = liftSNaN recip
        fromRational = SNaN . fromRational
```

You'd need more type classes to get the full `Float` experience of course, but as you can see it's pretty easy boilerplate once the `liftSNaN*` functions are defined. Given that, the `SNaN` constructor turns a value in any `RealFloat` type into one that will explode if it's a NaN and you use it in any operation (some of these you might arguably want to work on NaNs, maybe `==` and/or `show`; you can vary to taste). `unSNaN` turns any `SNaN` back into a quiet NaN type.

It's still not directly using the `Float` (or `Double`, or whatever) type, but if you just change your type signatures pretty much everything will just work; the `Num` and `Show` instances I've given mean that numeric literals will just as easily be accepted as `SNaN Float` as they will be `Float`, and they `show` the same too. If you get sick of typing `SNaN` in the type signatures you could easily `type Float' = SNaN Float`, or even:

```
import Prelude hiding (Float)
import qualified Prelude as P

type Float = SNaN P.Float
```

Though I'd bet that would cause confusion for someone eventually! But with that the exact same source code should compile and work, provided you've filled in all the type classes you need and you're not calling any other code you can't modify that hard-codes particular concrete types (rather than accepting any type in an appropriate type class).

This is basically an elaboration on Uli Köhler's first suggestion of providing a `Num` instance for `Maybe Float`. I've just used NaNs directly to represent NaNs, rather than `Nothing`, and used `isNan` to detect them instead of case analysis on the `Maybe` (or `isJust`).

The advantages of using a newtype wrapper over `Maybe` are:

1. You avoid introducing another "invalid" value to the doing (`Just NaN` vs `Nothing`), that  you have to worry about when converting to/from regular floats.
2. Newtypes are unboxed in GHC; an `SNaN Float` is represented at runtime identically to the corresponding `Float`. So there's no additional space overhaead for the `Just` cell, and converting back and forth between `SNaN Float` and `Float` are free operations. `SNaN` is just a tag that determines whether you would like implicit "if NaN then explode" checks inserted into your operations.